# Induced orientation on the boundary of a $1$-dimensional manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, orientation

Consider a $1$-dimensional smooth compact manifold with boundary $M$. Since $M$ is $1$-dimensional, then $\partial M$ is a $0$-dimensional manifold and it will have an induced orientation. I want to clarify some things about this. An orientation for a $0$-dimensional manifold is simply a function $\epsilon:\partial M\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ . Now given an outward-pointing vector field $Y$ of $M$ is the induced orientation $\epsilon$ on $\partial M$ the one such that $\epsilon \cdot Y$ is positively oriented with respect to the orientation of $M$. From the definitions of induced orientation that I found, from the book "Introduction to manifolds" I belive this will be it but I wanted discuss this with more detail.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the sentence '$\varepsilon \cdot Y$  is positively oriented' doesn't make sense.

Comment: For $M = [0,1]$, with usual orientation (that is $\partial_x$ is a positive basis), the induced orientation on $\partial M = \{0,1\}$ is $\{(0,-), (1,+)\}$. Note that there is no outward pointing vector field that does not vanish on $M$ since either it points outward at $0$ and inward at $1$ or the converse

Comment: Then what if I ask $\epsilon \cdot Y (p)$ to be positively-oriented for $p\in \partial M$?

Comment: An orientation for $M$ must first be given, before an induced orientation on $\partial M$ can be defined, so your first two sentences do not hold together. Perhaps the later phrase "... an outward-pointing vector field $Y$ on $M$..." represents an attempt to choose an orientation on $M$, but that phrase does not make any sense: What does "outward" even mean at points of $M - \partial M$?

Answer (score 4):

If $Y$ is a (non-vanishing) outward-pointing vector field on $\partial M$, it defines an orientation on $\partial M$ exactly as you outlined: for $p \in \partial M$, define $\varepsilon (p) = 1$ if and only if $(Y(p))$ is a positively oriented basis of $T_pM$ with respect to the orientation of $M$.